# Javascript to control Google Slides presentations on kiosk screen

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I have a few Google Slides presentations which I want to display on a kiosk screen. Each presentation is gfx heavy so joining them all into one single is not the best way.

Would I be able to use javascript to control embedded presentations, to

- Switch between presentation currently displayed
- Make sure presentation is in fullscreen

Comment: I had thought using <iframe> and changing src - but that would break full screen mode